# Changes to Map doesn't cause view to be rerendered

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am using a persisted observable `Map` in mobx. when adding or deleting a key from the map, the view is not rerendered. persistence still works. I am using `mobx-persist` package fwiw. Why is the view not being rerendered?

(Note: not a problem with my component, there are other mobx datastructures being observed by the component that cause rerender with out problems.

relevant bits of code from my `Store`:

```
@persist('map') @observable comparing = new Map();

@action addToCompare(item) {
    console.log('addToCompare');
    this.comparing.set(item.id,item);
}

@action removeFromCompare({id}){
    this.comparing.delete(id);
}
```

Persistence is working as expected. Changes to the map are persisted to LocalStorage as expected.

Comment: Interesting. For testing purposes, does your component re-render with just `@observable comparing = new Map();`? It might also be worth testing the `observable.map`: `@persist('map') @observable comparing = observable.map({});`

Comment: @Tholle neither made a difference. I was thinking that perhaps it is how the data is being passed to the components. not sure.

Comment: I see. If `@observable comparing = new Map();` didn't make the view re-rerender, it might have to do with how you dereference it in your component. Can you share the component that won't re-render?

Comment: @Tholle i got it. by declaring `const comparing = this.props.comparing.values()` at the top of my render function and passing it to all child components that would need to be rerendered in case of the change. Voila, the view is now rerendered. It looks like react's reconciliation algorithm is the culprit here.